# true normal with fresnel creates awkward effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have a project where I have edited the normals of an object and created a shader for it. I wanted to add a rimligt to the shader but when I try to use the normal output from the geometry node it uses the edited normals and does not look right. Instead, I plugged in the true normal function from the geometry node.

[image]

when I plug it into the fresnel it gives me this weird blocky effect.
[image]

this is because the true normal gives me the unedited normals without any smooth shading.
[image]
Is there any way to smooth the result I get? I will upload my file below.
[image]

Comment: So, you want the unedited normals, but with smooth shading?

Comment: yes I want to be able to have the smooth original normals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you already on your way with Geometry Nodes?

This group will return the geometric vertex-normals, linearly interpolated :

[image]

... it can be picked up in a shader:

[image]

I can't be sure this does it for you.. but here's the contrast:

[image]

Custom Normal  / True Normal / Geo Normal

[image]